# Unique key based on many-to-many pivot table

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many, relations

I have to manage artists and albums tables:

```
| artists      |  | albums       |  | album_artist |
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+
| id           |  | id           |  | id           |
| artist       |  | album        |  | album_id     |
| created_at   |  | created_at   |  | artist_id    |
| updated_at   |  | updated_at   |  +--------------+
+--------------+  +--------------+
```

Keeping in mind that this is a many-to-many relation, I do need to find a way to get the album-artist(s) pair unique, since albums may have the same name yet belonging to different artists (f.e. "Greatest Hits" album of 2Pac and "Greatest Hits" of Notorious BIG).

Is there a known way/pattern to address this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest and probably most common way would be to declare the *(album_id, artist_id)* pair of columns a unique composite key.

There are two variations of this approach. First, you can keep the current structure of the *album_artist* table and simply [add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) a unique constraint on the said two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE album_artist
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_album_artist
  UNIQUE (album_id, artist_id);
```

There are more options to adding a UNIQUE constraint, which can be found in the linked manual.

The second variation is to get rid of the *id* column and declare *(album_id, artist_id)* to be the primary key of the table, as [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) has suggested in a comment:

```
ALTER TABLE album_artist
DROP PRIMARY KEY;  /* assuming id has actually been declared
                      as the PK; if not, omit this step */

ALTER TABLE album_artist
DROP id;

ALTER TABLE album_artist
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_album_artist
  PRIMARY KEY (album_id, artist_id);
```

A junction table like your *album_artist* table, which stores no additional information beyond the table references, usually does not need to be referenced by other tables – at least, not often enough to justify the need for a dedicated ID column. The second variation, therefore, may be more appropriate. Rick's other useful thoughts on implementation of a junction table can be found in [his blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

If another table needs to reference an album and an artist as a valid combination (i.e. one that exists in the junction table), it can simply use a composite foreign key to reference *album_artist*:

```
FOREIGN KEY (album_id, artist_id) REFERENCES album_artist (album_id, artist_id)
```

It is only when you need to reference the junction table often (that is, from many tables) that I would argue the first approach, which allows you to keep a dedicated PK column in the junction table, would be more useful.

Comment: What if the album_artist table had more columns? Does it change anything?

Comment: @arniotaki: Most likely it doesn't, but what columns do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking about a relationship I am designing. Lets say that we want to add characteristics that are unique to this relationship. Lets imagine for this example that the name of the artist would change according to the album. We should add an artist name in the relation table right?

Comment: @arniotaki: Well, this specific example certainly doesn't change anything for me. Either variation of the approach (a sole composite PK on `(album_id, artist_id)` or a surrogate PK + composite UNIQUE constraint) could still be taken. Having looked at this a little more, I can't think of any scenario where any additional columns would matter. For me, which variation to take would depend on whether the junction table needs to be referenced by many tables. (If it does, I would most likely keep the surrogate PK.)

Comment: You would choose surrogate PK for better - faster use on your side. Does it change anything in the memory or so that we should consider?

Comment: My main considerations for choosing the surrogate PK are (1) working with a single-column reference is easier than with a composite one and (2) the former takes less space to store than the latter. I'd say they would trump most other considerations that might emerge, but each individual scenario may still have its specifics that could affect the final decision.